# jUnit restful API with real call

Tags: java, android, api, unit-testing, junit

I want to jUnit my api calls. I am making API calls using RxAndroid. Right now my test cases works around mock data. And we have good amount of unit test cases working with will mock data and Mockito.

My query is how we can test these test cases with real time api calls. Calling real api has lot of challenges like waiting time, performing async calls etc.I would like to accomplish this with jUnit test cases which runs over JVM.

I am aware of utilities like [MockServer](http://www.mock-server.com/) But is there a better way to do it.

Also please suggest is it a good way to execute your jUnit test case connecting to a real server?